# Doctrine and composite unique keys

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I want to do composite unique key in doctrine.
Those are my fields:

```php
/**
 * @var string $videoDimension
 *
 * @Column(name="video_dimension", type="string", nullable=false)
 */
private $videoDimension;

/**
 * @var string $videoBitrate
 *
 * @Column(name="video_bitrate", type="string", nullable=false)
 */
private $videoBitrate;
```

How can I show doctrine, that those combined together are composite unique key?

Answer (score 273, accepted):

Answer the question:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\UniqueConstraint;

/**
 * Common\Model\Entity\VideoSettings
 *
 * @Table(name="video_settings", 
 *    uniqueConstraints={
 *        @UniqueConstraint(name="video_unique", 
 *            columns={"video_dimension", "video_bitrate"})
 *    }
 * )
 * @Entity
 */
```

See [@UniqueConstraint](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref_uniqueconstraint)

Comment: Thanks for the information~
As a note, if you solved your own question, while you can't accept immediately, it's generally good form to accept your own answer, just so if people are searching, it shows as there is an acceptable answer.

Comment: Is it possible to do it with `-ToOne` associations (foreign keys)?

Comment: I know this is old post, but @Dimitry K it is possible. Just you need to use column name as in your @ORM\JoinColumn(name="join_table_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false). Here is 'join_table_id'.

Comment: Note that you have to provide _column_ names, not field names. So you have to convert camelCase to snake_case and append `_id` for associations, because that's how Doctrine generates column names.

Comment: names are autogenerated
`@Table(uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columns={"case_id", "duration"})})` and nothing else matter

Comment: and after my decision that it can be not unique it looks `@Table(indexes={@Index(columns={"case_id", "duration"})})`

Answer (score 55):

In case someone want use **PHP 8 Attributes** instead of Doctrine annotations:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity]
#[ORM\UniqueConstraint(
  name: 'video_unique_idx',
  columns: ['video_dimension', 'video_bitrate']
)]
```

Answer (score 27):

I find it more verbose to `use` only ORM and then prefix `ORM` in annotations. Also note that you can break annotation to several lines to make it more readable especially if you have several items to mention (index in the example below).

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * VideoSettings
 *
 * @ORM\Cache(usage="NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\VideoSettingsRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="emails", uniqueConstraints={
 *      @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="dimension_bitrate", columns={"video_dimension", "video_bitrate"})
 * }, indexes={
 *      @ORM\Index(name="name", columns={"name"})
 * })
 */
class VideoSettings
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I came across it while looking for a way to create composite PK and thought it could use some update.

Things are actually much simpler if what you need is a Composite Primary Key. (Which, of course, guarantees uniqueness) Doctrine documentation contains some nice examples by this url: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html

So the original example could look something like this:

```
/**
 * @var string $videoDimension
 *
 * @ORM\Id @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
private $videoDimension;

/**
 * @var string $videoBitrate
 *
 * @ORM\Id @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
private $videoBitrate;
```

A few notes here:

1. Column "name" is omitted since Doctrine is able to guess it based on
   the property name
2. Since `videoDimension` and `videoBitrate` are both parts of the PK - there is no need to specify `nullable = false`
3. If required - the Composite PK may be composed of foreign keys, so feel free to add some relational mappings

Comment: What you did is a composite primary key. Sure it will be unique, but it's a primary key... ;)

Comment: Well yes, I think I've mentioned that in my answer :) Actually the term "unique index" would be more appropriate in OP's case if he didn't mean to create PK (that's what the accepted answer does). But since the question contains a weird term "composite unique key" - I don't see why we can't assume it to be a composite primary key - at least that's what I've been looking for when I came across this question. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

XML version :

```
<unique-constraints>
    <unique-constraint columns="column1,column2" name="give_some_explicit_name" />
</unique-constraints>
```

More details in the docs :

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/xml-mapping.html#defining-indexes-or-unique-constraints